# htaccess rewrite all incoming request to base url

Tags: .htaccess

Is it possible to reroute all incoming requests to a the base index page.
Also as it is a wordpress site, I'd like to remove everything after the url route.

ie a request to mysite.com/something.html
would redirect to mysite.com/

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /cms/
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I can now redirect, but
I can't get rid of the something.html part - which is causing me a problem

Comment: Is `something.html` an existing file? If yes, your rewriterule will not catch it.

Comment: To redirect you need to add the `R` flag. So `[L]` will become `[L,R]`.

Comment: @Seybsen - no, it's a one page app and I want to catch all requests and funnel them to the index page.